# What database should I use to store a vast number of potentially large nested hash structures?

Tags: database, nosql, bigdata

I want to store a large number (hundreds of millions to hundreds of billions) of arbitrarily nested hash structures (typically 4-6 levels), with some attributes at the top level. I do not need to query inside the nested hash, only on the top-level attributes. Querying must be possible without writing code, typically for exact matches on the top-level attributes. When updating records, I'd like to be able to update only the portion of the sub-hash structures that have changed and not have to read/write the entire record. The db must have bindings/drivers for C, Ruby, and Python.

Mongodb would seem to be ideal, except that there's a 4MB (and soon to be 8MB or 16MB) limit on individual items. Most of these items will be small, but some of them may be 100-200MB and potentially larger.

Is there another database that matches these criteria?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what that hash structure might look like?

Comment: No, but I might be able to give you something that looks similar. What specifically do you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

Redis does not meet many of your stated requirements, but it *could* if you're willing to build somethingon top of it.

Two key things are missing.

First of all Redis does not support nested hashes.  But if you're willing to use some sort of encoding, a value can point to a key with another hash.  This would allow arbitrary nested structures.  With this hack, updates only need to update the portion that changed.  You'd have to write this layer in C, Ruby, and Python.  But it would be pretty simple.

Secondly there isn't an interface that lets you query it without writing code.  But that should be pretty easy to write.  And you only need to write it once.

Comment: If I'm going to write a layer to store sub-hashes in separate records, I could just as easily do that for mongodb. I'd worry about read performance in reassembling large structures though, and that would also explode the number of items/rows in the target table by a few orders of magnitude.

Comment: @fields: Yes, you can do that for mongodb.  The performance with Redis is likely to be better than mongodb, but I agree with you that read performance could be an issue.  And yes, it would explode the number of items.

Comment: Using redis, how do you query for an item/row by more than one attribute? Everything I've seen in the documentation and used has items referenced by a single key.

Comment: Well it should! This functionality should exist by 2012! Shame on you, community!

Answer (score 0):

You can do post-processing. You're going to have to give separate names for the 'id' keys inside of your subhashes, but if you do that, something like this should work...so far so good anyway:

given a stored hash like so:

```
x => #<Company id: 16, name: "JRapid", markets: {"markets"=>"[{:market_id=>12, :market_name=>\"enterprise software\", :parents=>[{:parent_id=>12, :name=>\"enterprise software\", :grandparents=>{:parent_id=>12, :name=>\"enterprise software\"}}]}, {:market_id=>38, :market_name=>\"cloud computing\", :parents=>[{:parent_id=>38, :name=>\"cloud computing\", :grandparents=>{:parent_id=>38, :name=>\"cloud computing\"}}]}, {:market_id=>409, :market_name=>\"development platforms\", :parents=>[{:parent_id=>409, :name=>\"development platforms\", :grandparents=>{:parent_id=>409, :name=>\"development platforms\"}}]}, {:market_id=>1132, :market_name=>\"developer tools\", :parents=>[{}]}]"}, locations: {"locations"=>"[{:location_id=>1624, :location_name=>\"california\", :parents=>[{}]}, {:location_id=>1703, :location_name=>\"sunnyvale\", :parents=>[{}]}]"}, follower_count: 8, high_concept: "Rapid development Java cloud platform", product_desc: "JRapid is a Platform as a Service and is the fastes...", urls: {"blog_url"=>"http://www.jrapid.com/blog", "logo_url"=>"https://angel.co/images/icons/startup-nopic.png", "thumb_url"=>"https://angel.co/images/icons/startup-nopic.png", "company_url"=>"http://www.jrapid.com", "twitter_url"=>"http://www.twitter.com/JRapid", "angellist_url"=>"https://angel.co/jrapid"}, status: nil, created_at_or_updated_at: {"created_at"=>"2010-07-21T18:48:32Z", "updated_at"=>"2011-05-07T20:00:37Z"}, screenshots: {"screenshots"=>"[[nil]]"}, created_at: "2012-08-07 05:37:54", updated_at: "2012-08-07 05:37:54">
```

You could do something like this:

```
x = x.locations
x = x['locations']
x = eval(x)
x[0][:id]
 #=> 1624
```

WARNING: running eval() on a given string will take just about ANYTHING. So this might not be a "production mode" solution. In fact it isn't. But it will work for the interim until you learn how to use some real Document-DB solution.
AGAIN: WARNING! Running eval can be dangerous!

(if this helped you, please one-up---I'm banned from SO for asking too many questions and need more rep points to be able to ask questions again)